# How Do I Lock My Text Element? (HTML)

Tags: html, text, locking, element, window-resize

So I'm trying to lock my text element so when I resize my browser window, half the text wont transition downwards.

Full-Screen Example: 
"I Am a Text"

Smaller-Screen Example: 
"I Am 
 a 
 Text"

I want it to no longer collapse.

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<a href="Shop.html"><h1 id="MHB">SEE MORE</h1></a>
```

And here's my CSS code:

```
#MHB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 314px;
  left: 807.5px;
  color: #716F6F;
  font-family: Julius Sans One;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Set a min-width on the container? Also, place the `<a>`-tag inside the `<h1>`-tag, please? Inline-elements should be placed inside block-elements, even though that horrible syntax is valid HTML 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#MHB{
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Simply put above lines which is never wrap text even screen is too small